# String function returns strange value

Tags: c++, string

I've got a function returning a binary representation of a byte:

```
std::string ToBinary(unsigned char &Num)
{
    char str[8];
    char Symb = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i<8)
    {
        _asm
        {
            //push al
            shr byte[Num], 1
            mov al, 0
            adc al, 30h
            mov byte[Symb], al
            //pop al
        }
        str[7-i] = Symb;
        i++;
    }
    return std::string(str);
}
```

And it's call:

```
std::string BinOut = ToBinary(ByteValue);
```

The problem is that instead of getting an 8-char string it returns 14-char string. Obviously, inside the function str shows correct value. How do I make it return 8 characters?

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: `return std::string(str, 8);` See (4) in: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string  Does not need NULL termination and allows embedded NULLs.

Comment: `str` is not null terminated so you have UB

Comment: `Silly mistake: forgot about null terminator ` Is that an answer? If so, please don't put that into your ***question***. Instead upvote some of the answers, which state the error and accept it, if you are happy with the answer.

Answer (score 5):

The constructor of `std::string` which accepts a pointer to `char` requires that the pointed string is null terminated. Your `str` is not null terminated and so the behaviour of the program is undefined.

You can either

- Use a `char[9]` and set the last character to `'\0'`. This works only if the `str` doesn't contain any zero bytes since the first one would be the terminator.
- Or use the constructor `std::string(char *s, std::size_t count)` which doesn't have such requirement.

Comment: You could also keep `char str[8];` and then use `return {std::begin(str), std::end(str)};` to list initialize the returned string.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is caused because your character array does not contain a terminating null character. One solution is to allocate an array with one extra character so you can terminate it with null:

```
char str[9]
//...
str[8] = '\0'
```

Alternatively, you can use an overloaded string constructor that allows you to pass in a parameter for the number of characters to use from the input array:

std::string(str, 8);

Comment: That's an overkill. Just use another overload of `std::string`. It also won't work properly in the general case (where there WILL be null byte in the sequence!)

Comment: @SergeyA Yes, I am assuming that the preceding code correctly builds the array of 8 non-null characters.